# verify barman backed up files after failure

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I have a barman that get backups from a postgres installed on another server. its config is:

```
    active: True
    archive_mode: on
    archived_count: 47588
    archiver: True
    archiver_batch_size: 0
    backup_method: rsync
    backup_options: BackupOptions(['exclusive_backup'])
    bandwidth_limit: None
    check_timeout: 30
    compression: gzip
    custom_compression_filter: None
    custom_decompression_filter: None
    disabled: False
    failed_count: 0
    immediate_checkpoint: True
    is_archiving: True
    is_superuser: True
    last_archived_time: 2018-11-17 14:49:58.810545+03:30
    last_archived_wal: 0000000100002ACC0000003B
    last_backup_maximum_age: 7 days (latest backup: 6 hours, 3 minutes, 11 seconds )
    last_failed_time: None
    last_failed_wal: None
    max_incoming_wals_queue: None
    minimum_redundancy: 1
    msg_list: []
    network_compression: True
    parallel_jobs: 15
    path_prefix: None
    pgespresso_installed: False
    post_archive_retry_script: None
    post_archive_script: None
    post_backup_retry_script: None
    post_backup_script: None
    pre_archive_retry_script: None
    pre_archive_script: None
    pre_backup_retry_script: None
    pre_backup_script: None
    recovery_options: RecoveryOptions([])
    replication_slot: None
    replication_slot_support: True
    retention_policy: REDUNDANCY 2
    retention_policy_mode: auto
    reuse_backup: None
...
```

about some days ago we had some problem on postgres and barman failed to back up. now as I list backup logs I see this:

```
20181117T011505 - Sat Nov 17 08:46:53 2018 - Size: 2.2 TiB - WAL Size: 9.8 GiB (tablespaces: ...)
20181116T011506 - Fri Nov 16 08:48:28 2018 - Size: 2.2 TiB - WAL Size: 38.3 GiB (tablespaces: ...)
20181114T011504 - FAILED
```

I checked my postgres tablespace and its size is exactly 2.2TB.
Now the questions are:

- are backups correct?
- did I lost data due to downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard barman commands: `barman status`, `barman show-backup` and `barman check-backup`. See [documentation](http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.5/).

Comment: all of these commands returned 'OK'. but fail status of `20181114T011504` is still there and it does not go away. I'm not sure if my backups are really OK. what should I do about that FAILED status?

Comment: @Alireza why do you worry if it's clear that you have full backups from later date which are OK.  Just one day is missing so you may be unable to restore to that point in time. otherwise no problems here...

Comment: another q. what is WAL and why it's much less than DB size?

Comment: "what is WAL" please RTFM, its here https://www.postgresql.org/search/?u=%2Fdocs%2F11%2F&q=WHAT_TO_SEARCH_FOR